# Проблема с модальными окнами Bootstrap

Tags: вёрстка

Имеется Bootstrap 4 на сайте и модальное окно. Однако, при открытии этого модального кнопка съезжает вниз. Как это можно пофиксить? Встречается только на телефоне [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD: такое поведение только в мобильном Хроме

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена путем очистки кэша другим путем, через очистку истории, а не очистку локального хранилища